# Отсортировать три числа в порядке возрастания С++, используя указатели

Tags: c++, указатели

```
void sort (int * a, int * b, int * c) {
// вот здесь тело метода, которое нужно заполнить
}

int main () {

int a = 2, b = 3, c = 1;
sort (a,b,c);
cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;

}
```

Comment: И что? В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, сравнивайте и меняйте в нужном порядке...

Типа

```
if (*a > *b) 
{
    int t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
```

Ну, и так далее. Как просто расставить три числа в порядке возрастания - это вы знаете? Вот так и поступите с числами `*a`, `*b` и `*c`.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, вот так

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void sortInt (int* a, int* b, int* c) {
    if(*a>*b) swap(*a,*b);
    if(*a>*c) swap(*a,*c);
    if(*b>*c) swap(*b,*c);
}


int main()
{

    int a = 2, b = 3, c = 1;
    sortInt (&a,&b,&c);
    cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Мой include в реальных проектах лучше не юзать. Функция свап лежит в заголовочнике utility, если компилятор не с++11, то тогда в algorithm